# SOA essentials business integration scenario?

Tags: soa, business-intelligence, application-server

I am new to business integration. 
It is under my consideration that as a software engineer one's task is to design/deploy web services using an application server and some integration design tool and to provide mediation software modules to decouple existing web services.

The thing is I am not familiar with SOA philosophy and am still a bit lost in various documentation.

I understand the tools used are application servers(like WebSphere or Jboss) development environments (like Java EE Eclipse or IBM Integration Designer).

I need a concrete example from Alpha to Omega on how a SW engineer acts in deploying a business integration project.

E.g what kind of enterprise could one collaborate with and what kind of business logic has to implement...

I know my question is vague but I am starting from scratch and I need to understand essential concepts.

Any advice would be accepted as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exceptionally broad question and myriad answers.
I suggest you start with [this](http://www.packtpub.com/service-oriented-architecture-made-simple/book). It should provide a good begining understanding of SOA.

Comment: Thank you!
I also encountered some IBM redbooks which are pretty enlightening 
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247234.html?Open